# Аналог phpbb для Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, phpbb, forum

есть ли аналог phpBB, но не для пыхи, а для джанго? Т.е. нечто, что легко способно создавать форумы. Или я все же потяну phpBB, не имея никаких знаний о php? Просто не совсем понимаю как он работает.

Comment: А разве суть джанги не в том, чтобы самому можно было писать phpBB?

Comment: Я крайне молод в этом деле, лишь недавно начал увлекаться джангой и программированием в целом. То есть вы хотите сказать, что django не требует подобных дополнений и тот же форум вполне можно написать на чистой джанге?

Comment: Вполне можно. Как и на чистом петоне без джанги

Comment: @РашенБеар хотел бы я посмотреть, как Вы напишите форум на чистом "петоне")

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук 200к. и погнали

Answer (score 0):

А в чём трудность самому написать форум?

Если всё же хочется что-то готовое, то вот вполне достойные решения:

1. `Misago`: [forum](https://misago-project.org/)/[git](https://github.com/rafalp/Misago)
2. `Django-machina`: [forum](https://demo.machina-forum.io/)/[git](https://github.com/ellmetha/django-machina)

Со вторым будет проще работать.